# Is MVC from Microsoft the new Struts for Dot net?

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, struts

I have not used MVC but am merely wondering as a Java person, hence the q.

Answer (score 2):

I never really worked with Struts, but this wiki might be of use for comparisson:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks

Comment: Interesting overview. Shows that ASP.NET MVC is one of the few MVC frameworks which are totally ORM independent. Also, the push/pull distinction was completely new to me. Never thought that there were some MVC frameworks that start with the View and have it pull data from the Controllers. I wonder when the pull model would make more sense than push?

Comment: "...one of the few MVC frameworks which are totally ORM independent..." - this is not true.  You can use Spring, Struts, Wicket, and any other web MVC framework that I know for Java without  having to use an ORM solution.

Comment: I think ORM-independent means that it's not tied to a specific ORM, not that you can use it without an ORM.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer... yes. They are both MVC frameworks, targeting different development stacks. That said, there are a bunch of different MVC frameworks and they all have differences in how they help developers work within that pattern. MonoRails for example is another ASP.NET MVC framework.